# Is it illegal to enter a website with an account that is not yours?

Tags: software, privacy

I worked as a developer in a company and I had some of the employees' passwords. They are saved in my Google account.

What are the consequences of using these passwords to enter as another person? Assuming that I entered them in a program that I created.

Comment: Depends on the jurisdiction but unauthorized use of a computer system may be illegal. Either felony or misdemeanor in some US states.

Comment: Is this [related to your other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/78574/1270)? Start talking to a lawyer instead of asking internet strangers.

Comment: "With great power comes great responsibility".

Comment: One piece of advice, if that is your real name and photo on your profile, maybe change it... you may not want your past employer to see this kind of question/you admitting you have that information.

Comment: It does not matter that you created the program, it is the property of your former employer. If you do not have your own account to access it, you are not an authorized user.

Comment: As a quick heads-up you will want to read this sentence: 46 months in federal prison for using old passwords of a former colleague "to just look at things"...https://www.justice.gov/usao-sdtx/pr/former-cardinals-official-sentenced-prison-astros-computer-intrusions

Comment: Knowing two things may change the answer. 1) Has the account owner given you permission to use it?  2) Are you talking about *intentional use*, or is this a case of the browser automatically logging in using someone else's stored credentials before you have a chance to enter your own?

Comment: “some of the employees' passwords […] are saved in my Google account.” Is that your personal Google account, or one belonging to your previous employer? If your personal one, how did the passwords get saved there? Did your employer authorise that, and are they aware? (Or if a company account, are you still authorised to use it?)

Comment: When is an account "yours" how would you even start to define who an imaginary concept belongs to?

Comment: Probably obvious, but... You don't have permission to do this, right? There isn't any contractual relationship where the company is paying you to regain access after messing the system up, right?

Comment: @Tvde1 We define property rights in imaginary things all the time. Copyright and patent, for trivial examples, but also arguably stocks or real estate.

Comment: Copyrights and real estate have a name (and social security/passport number) assigned. An account does not

Comment: @Tvde1, I'm not sure what you mean. The credentials I use to log into my company network absolutely has my name attached. When I log in in the morning, the company knows it's me (or someone impersonating me, which would be bad)

Comment: Just a heads up, it's trivially easy to find which company you used to work for, the internet leaves a lot of trails that are hard to cover. Also this being a hot network question now, if anyone from your work uses stack exchange there is a reasonable chance they could come across it

Comment: In the US there is a saying that the prosecutor could “Indict a Ham Sandwich”, if it’s  for a supposed violation of the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act, expect to be found guilty if you have ever interacted with the computer system in question.  It basically boils down to them saying they NOW wouldn’t have wanted you to do whatever you did THEN.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I infer from the use of the past tense "worked" that you no longer work for the company in question.  Also, from the fact that you are wondering whether there might be negative consequences, I infer that you do not have permission to use the systems in question.

The specific consequences will depend on where the company and its computers are located, as well as on the nature of the systems you log in to and on what you do with those systems, but it's certainly possible to receive a penalty of several years' imprisonment.  The fact that you created the system in question makes no difference.

Comment: @Vasyl Yovdiy Yes for unauthorized access.

Comment: @DarkBee that absolutely does not matter here. Even if he were the full owner, if he needed an external account to access the data it would be problematic

Comment: @ikenas If I go into your house without permission it's still illegal.  If you found me on your couch watching your TV, would you accept my defence that I was "just watching"?  That I hadn't damaged anything?  That I used a key under the mat to let myself in, so it was therefore legitimate?  The law certainly wouldn't, and I think you'd be glad for it.

Comment: the situation in question is not much like entering a personal residence. If people can get into your home you are at great risk, your quality of life will be greatly damaged. Logging on to netflix without paying has no such component, it's more like watching someone's TV through a gap in their blinds. Most people would not think years in prison is a reasonable response to that.

Comment: @timeskull The question does not seem to be about using someone else's Netflix account to binge some show. It's appears to be about unauthorized access of proprietary company systems for which most reasonable people do indeed find years in prison to be a reasonable response... as evidenced by the criminal laws against it in almost every modern democracy. An unauthorized user having access to a company's IT resources also "puts them at great risk" and that's putting it mildly.

Comment: @timeskull It's the judge you have to convince... I'm not sure I'd place any bets.

Comment: @timeskull "Just watching" what's happening in a company's internal IT resources (without authorization) is quite literally industrial espionage.

Comment: @reirab Espionage should minimally entail, in addition to ”just watching”, at least one of the following. Either (1) the intent to use the information from "just watching" for material gain (not necessarily for yourself directly); or (2) an act of using the information from "just watching" purposefully for material gain. I would even say that (1) alone is something like "conspiracy to commit industrial espionage" and not actual espionage. Doesn't imply, of course, that "just watching" is a good thing, or allowed in a particular place. Just that it is not espionage by itself. Do you agree?

Comment: @LinearChristmas a brief search did not find any statute that defines "industrial espionage" either as a crime or otherwise, so that leaves us with the dictionary definition, and both dictionaries I consulted defined it only in terms of obtaining information covertly without regard to the intended use of the information.

Comment: @LinearChristmas I wouldn't agree. I would especially disagree with (1) not constituting espionage on its own. Espionage is the act of collecting the information (without authorization.) How (or whether) it's ultimately used to one's advantage is another matter. I would actually say pretty much the opposite: actually using the information once you already have it _isn't_ espionage. Just collecting it is (according to both dictionary definitions and personal experience... I design software for counterintelligence gear.)

Comment: @LinearChristmas To use a non-industrial example, a General making decisions based on intelligence reports he has received from spies on his side is not engaging in espionage. A spy collecting that information (regardless of whether any use for it is ever found) is, however, engaged in espionage.

Comment: @phoog That might leave *you* with those definitions. :) The definitions I found (in English), on average, tend to end the definitions with “... conducted for the purpose of enhancing a competitor's advantage in the marketplace”, or “for use by a competitor to achieve a competitive advantage”, or “to gain a business advantage”, or “for commercial purposes instead of purely national security”, or "one company steals secrets from another company with which it is competing". (and @reirab)

Comment: @LinearChristmas That's just the difference in purpose that distinguishes industrial espionage from state-level military/political espionage. Not what actually makes it espionage or not.

Comment: @reirab “I wouldn't agree. I would especially disagree with (1) not constituting espionage on its own” That is fair enough, thank you for clarifying. You also said "actually using the information once you already have it isn't espionage". I agree with this. Since you work in computer science-related fields, I might say the following to help clarify my (partially devil's advocate) position. Let A = “just watching”, B = "intent to use or act of using information from "just watching" (for material gain)". I was trying to argue for industrial espionage being A & B, not merely A, or merely B.

Comment: @reirab Maybe the comments are getting a bit excessive (sorry!). I did find a US-based “Economic espionage act of 1996”. It has a different emphasis than the industrial espionage we were discussing here, nor does it explicitly say "here is a definition of economic espionage". Yet, it begins by setting a minimal fine for 5 forms of economic espionage, with the explanatory statement "Whoever, intending or knowing that the offense will benefit ... knowingly". Maybe that's for a more general (legal-moral) reason. I am not an expert by any means. Thank you for the exchange anyhow! :)

Comment: "I go into your house without permission it's still illegal"  - but a tort, not a crime.

Comment: @JamesK trespass is a crime in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @LinearChristmas Industrial Espionage is "Anything containing A". No B required.

Answer (score 22):

There is no country tag, but for example in [france](/questions/tagged/france), that would be:

- 2 years in prison and 60.000€ fine just for getting in.
- 3 years in prison and 100.000€ fine if you modify anything.
- 5 years in prison and 150.000€ fine if what you are accessing is state-owned.

https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/id/LEGISCTA000006149839/

Comment: Are these additive sentences? Or do they replace each other as you go up the level of sentencing?

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st You can be *sentenced* on multiple counts, however, there is no additive *serving* of sentences in the French legal system, so you would only do the time, and pay the fine for the highest one.

Answer (score 7):

Unauthorized access of a computer system is often treated as breaking and entering, theft, and/or vandalism/destruction of property, depending on what you do while in the system; many jurisdictions have specific laws that reframe those concepts in terms of computer access, such as the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) of 1986 ([united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)).

Answer (score 7):

The legal portion of this answer has already been pretty succinctly covered by a couple other users. But I wanted to add some additional things to keep in mind.

As @phyrfox notes in their answer, under US law this would be considered a crime under the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act. A few more things to keep in mind for the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act (*Personal experience reference, basing the following two points off of what I learned in my Computer Science ethics course*):

- Unauthorized access can mean accessing a system you are no longer allowed to access, even if in the past you were allowed to access it. Think of it like using an old key to get into an office you *used* to work at; It would have been fine when you were actually still an employee, but if you don't work there anymore then it's just breaking and entering.
- Unauthorized access can also mean accessing a system you are *allowed* to access, but accessing it in a way that goes beyond the reasons you were given access in the first place. For example, someone working customer service for a company probably has open access to customer files for the purposes of providing service to customers. If that employee were to access files so they could get someone's number and call them up to ask them for a date that would be a clear violation of the limitations on the access they were given.

In your scenario, the first bullet point is probably the most important. You would be accessing the systems of a company ( or accounts of employees of a company ) that no longer employs you and so you've lost *authorized* access to that system.

To throw in my two cents as a professional developer, I'd also note that the scenario you've described would be a pretty clear ethical violation and most people would expect you to know that. I wouldn't be surprised if you had signed documents at the start of the job stating that you acknowledge actions like that would be a violation of company conduct policies. This is to say that I doubt any employer or criminal investigator would be sympathetic to "I didn't know it was wrong/illegal".

I'd also be curious why you had employee passwords in the first place. Personally I'm having a hard time thinking of why you would ever need to know the login passwords of other users. If you needed to do something for a user, you should either have had the admin privileges to do it directly in the system or you should have walked the employee through what they needed to do once they are signed into their own account on their own computer. But even if there were legitimate reasons to have them and/or it was normal for your work place, I would think it would have been expected of you to remove those passwords from your account the second you no longer needed them for the relevant task. Again, this brings us back to some of the precision around what constitutes "authorized access" of a system. The legality of someone's actions in your scenario depends on them only using those passwords within the time frame and for the reasons that were specifically expected of them to perform their job.

Comment: As someone who does IT assistance for an institution: I only handle temporary passwords which become invalid once used and require setting a new password immediately after use. This way I can not know their real passwords, or - on-demand - lock out a user from the system by assigning a password [e.g. if they leave]. *Technically* I can make permanent passwords, but unless I do so for enumerated reasons, I violate the system integrity rules that ban me from having access to other people's accounts but for troubleshooting and fixing, after which I have to re-assign a new temporary password.

Comment: Of note: the CFAA applies only to a subset of all computers, specifically those either: a) belonging to the federal government, b) belonging to bank, or c) computers that are used in or that affect interstate or foreign commerce. But that means every computer connected to the Internet is protected under the CFAA, so the only computers that might fall outside the scope are your Arduino chips and your local media server (maybe, MAYBE, your alarm system)

Answer (score 4):

**What are the consequences of using these passwords to enter as another person?**

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

Assuming the passwords were used in the way described and was unauthorised, as a minimum this would be an offence contrary to [section 1 of the Computer Misuse Act 1990](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1?timeline=false), (with emboldened consequences):

> (1) A person is guilty of an offence if—
>
> - (a) he causes a computer to perform any function with intent to secure access to any program or data held in any computer, or to enable any such access to be secured;
> - (b) the access he intends to secure, or to enable to be secured, is unauthorised; and
> - (c) he knows at the time when he causes the computer to perform the function that that is the case.
>
> (2) The intent a person has to have to commit an offence under this section need not be directed at—
>
> - (a) any particular program or data;
>
> (b) a program or data of any particular kind; or
>
> (c) a program or data held in any particular computer.
>
> (3) A person guilty of an offence under this section shall be liable—
>
> - (a) **on summary conviction in England and Wales, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding 12 months or to a fine not exceeding the statutory maximum or to both;**
> - (b) **on summary conviction in Scotland, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding 12 months or to a fine not exceeding the statutory maximum or to both;**
> - (c) **on conviction on indictment, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding two years or to a fine or to both.**

Depending on what actions are taken, there are more serious/aggravating offences at:

[Section 2](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/2?timeline=false) - Unauthorised access with intent to commit or facilitate commission of further offences.

[Section 3](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/3?timeline=false) - Unauthorised acts with intent to impair, or with recklessness as to impairing, operation of computer, etc.

[Section 3ZA](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/3ZA?timeline=false) - Unauthorised acts causing, or creating risk of, serious damage.

Answer (score 0):

If you had your own password, you were at some time authorised to access these computers using your password. It is most likely the case that you are not authorised anymore after leaving your job. If the company messed up and didn't prevent the use of your password, then the fact that you are *capable* of getting to their computers still doesn't mean you are authorised.

If you had access to other people's passwords, you quite likely were never authorised to use them to get access to the company's computer. (I had access to ONE password of my boss that I was authorised to use for one specific set of purposes - after leaving the company I was absolutely NOT authorised anymore). So here you are just as unauthorised, but it would be much harder for you to come up with a halfway reasonable excuse for using your colleagues' passwords.

So don't use them. Destroy them. On your last day you should have informed the company which passwords you have, and leave it to them to decide if they trust you to destroy them, or to block those passwords. In my case, the password was destroyed on all computers that I have in my possession, and I would not dare even trying to see if the password still works if I hadn't destroyed it.

Answer (score 0):

## Do you have permission from the account owner?

If yes, the worst you might be guilty of is breaking the website's Terms of Service.

If no, you're breaking the computer hacking laws in your jurisdiction. The exact laws obviously differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, but signing into services with another person's account is a universally covered scenario, and almost always comes with criminal punishments (ie: jailtime is a strong possibility)

EDIT: The fact that you saved the passwords of other employees into a personal Google account can also constitute a criminal offense; you almost certainly did not have permission to take those passwords away from company systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be "Authorised". Depending upon the circumstances under which you came into possession of credentials, and any further binding obligations, you may or may not be "Authorised".

As the facts are stated, you should not even possess these credentials, let alone use them. It is a very serious matter for an ex-employee to be using shared credentials (or their own), even under the table and off the books. Depending upon your jurisdiction your access may be considered de facto evidence of a more serious act of mischief. In any case you will damage the owner of the installation if they are subject to mandatory breach reporting.

...and it is not necessarily what you have done, but what you are perceived to have done.. You would not want to be relying upon "A friend of the court" to clarify the circumstances, or the law, to the technological laity.

Plenty of examples, consider Warren Simondson, a former supplier of McKays Solicitors (Australia). It does not take much.

Answer (score -2):

If it is email accounts then there is the real possibility the company pays and owns the business email accounts and if you have there permission to use it you are not breaking any laws. A lot of private github accounts are also paid for by companies.  You are given access to upload your work there but that account is not the employees property. Also, the work pc is not the employees property.

It is unlikely that any work you do from your work pc will be done from accounts that are yours.

Answer (score -3):

Well if you are a developer you might have come across a few licensing agreements to certain software you'd have applied to use before.

depending on the license you have been granted, it either allows you to do as you please or be found guilty of a crime, so it's a 50/50 case also depending on geographical differences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What would happen if there is no license at all?

Comment: At some point I had a license to use Microsoft Office for £14; that license was available to employees of companies that had a site license from Microsoft. The license become invalid when I left the company. (So if all your employees had a license to use the software at work, they could get a private license for £14, bound to their employment).